# How To Make Dynamic $HTTP Request Using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ngmodel

In my controller I use `$http.get(..)` to request JSON from a URL which can take a day month and year as variables. These are set to today's date by default. I have three input boxes in my view and I am trying to allow users to change the URL using `ng-model` based on what they enter in these input boxes but I am unaware if this is the correct approach or is there a better way to solve the issue?

```
app.controller("View1Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
    function minTwoDigits(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var day = new Date().getDate();
    month = month+1;
    month = minTwoDigits(month);
    day = minTwoDigits(day);

    $http.get('http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_'+   year +'/month_'+ month +'/day_'+ day +'/master_scoreboard.json')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.games = data;
            console.log($scope.games);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code placed in your controller is only executed once, when the controller object is created. You can consider it a constructor. So if you want your code to be run more than once, you'll have to put it in a function and then run the function whenever anything changes.

So your controller could look like this instead:

```
app.controller("View1Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {

    // Run initialize once
    initialize();

    function initialize(){
        $scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();
        $scope.month = new Date().getMonth();
        $scope.day = new Date().getDate();
        $scope.month = month+1;

        loadGames();
    }

    function loadGames(){
        var year = $scope.year;
        var month = minTwoDigits($scope.month);
        var day = minTwoDigits($scope.day);

        $http.get('http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_'+   year +'/month_'+ month +'/day_'+ day +'/master_scoreboard.json')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.games = data;
                console.log($scope.games);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
            });
    }

    function minTwoDigits(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
});
```

Then you can run this `loadGames()` function when clicking a button, or as an ng-change event, like so:

```
<button ng-click="loadGames()">Load</button>
```

As per BOSS's answer, you can (and definitely should) separate some of this into a service, but it isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use service based approach when calling

```
angular.module('test')
  .service('testService', function ($http) {


      this.getValue= function (year,day,month) {
      var endpoint = "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_'+ year +'/month_'+ month +'/day_'+ day +'/master_scoreboard.json";

      return  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: endpoint
      });
    };
```

In your controller

```
app.controller("View1Ctrl", function($scope, testService) {

    $scope.getData= function () {
          testService.getValue( year,day,month).then(
             function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);

            },
            function errorCallback(response) {

            });


        };


}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling I was not approaching it in the right way even though I did manage to get something working I knew it wasn't correct but because I am new to AngualrJS I was looking for guidance. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: you can download a sample project that I gave build for https://github.com/noman57/login from here .. Mark as accepted if this answer helps :) @EoghanBuckley